# Show navigationItem in UITtableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uinavigationitem

I created one File it's Swift 
I add  class `Mypage: UITableViewController,`
After in Storyboard I add one New UITableviewController and add Class 
and in Editor Storyboard -> Embed in I add `UInavigateController`

now I use to going to this tableviewcontroller

```
let viewController:UITableViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Mypage") as! UITableViewController

self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

when I go to **Mypage** I don't See navigator and I don't see the Rightbutton

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()


        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

}
```

I need to see right bar button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Present "Mypage" with UINavigationController and Mypage as rootViewController

   ```
   let viewController:UITableViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Mypage") as! UITableViewController

   let navigationContoller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
   self.present(navigationContoller, animated: false, completion: nil)
   ```
2. Perform seque from button to the navigation controller on Storyboard.
   (Use control-drag on Button)
   [image]]

Comment: is not work I stay In my last view controller I can't push too next

Comment: I didn't copy and paste well the code, please try again.